# Show Donut / Pie Chart in bootstrap modal with legends

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, chart.js

I am new to chartjs and javascript.
Below is my code snippet. I am trying to load the pie/donut chart with legends in bootstrap Modal post the button is click.

Can anyone please help with simple JS.

(If its work I would like to show half donut graph in modal with legends is it possible?)

I have tried few ways to get desire result but still its load blank modal if i use it without going for modal its work perfectly on page load.

```
Html Code
========== 
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
<title>Pie Chart</title>
<link rel="stylesheet"    
href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script 
src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.4.0/Chart.min.js"> 
</script>
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
<script 
src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"> 
</script>

</head>

<body>
   <!-- <canvas id="chart-area" width="1256" height="256" ></canvas>-->
   <div class="container-fluid">
   <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modChart">
   <button  type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data- 
   target="#modChart">Check DB</button></a>
   </div>
   <div class="modal fade" id="modChart" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria- 
   labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
   <div class="modal-content">
   <div class="modal-header">
   <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
   <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span>
   </button>
   <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Chart</h4>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-body">
   <canvas id="mycanvas" width="256" height="256"></canvas>
   </div>
   </div>
   </div>
   </div>
<!-- html code over-->
<script> 
//java script start here
//defining the Pie chart details
var config = {
    type: 'pie',
    data: {
        labels: ["USSD", "URP", "MyTsel App", "Chatbot"],
        datasets: [{
            backgroundColor: ['rgb(12, 146, 204)',
                'rgb(255, 67, 0)',
                'rgb(131, 0, 255)',
                'rgb(250, 255, 0)'
            ],
            borderColor: ['rgb(12, 146, 204)',
                'rgb(255, 67, 0)',
                'rgb(131, 0, 255)',
                'rgb(250, 255, 0)'
            ],
            data: [73, 17, 3, 7],
        }]
    },
    options: {
        responsive: true,
        legend: {
            position: 'bottom',
            labels: {
                fontColor: "black",
                boxWidth: 20,
                padding: 20
            }
        }
    }
}; //Graph defination over here
  //Graph defination

$('#modChart').on('shown.bs.modal',function(event){
var ctx = $("#mycanvas").get(0).getContext("2d");
    //var ctx = document.getElementById('chart-area').getContext('2d');
    window.myPie = new Chart(ctx, config);
});
</script>
</body>  
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks,

I am able to resolve this. Please follow below GITHUB link for more details if anyone required.
I have used Flask web framework, Panda to load and read the CSV file, Ajax and JSON used for Client server Communication ( to Avoid the Refresh and reload), Chartjs is used for generating the Chart/Graph, CSS is used for generating a pulse effect for showing running status.

https://github.com/AG060982/flask-panda-chartjs-ajax-json-bootstrap_modal